# Iframe not working on Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, iframe

Im having some issues with Iframe not displaying on Wordpress. I've added this;

`<iframe src="https://link" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="no"></iframe>`

Unfortunately, when I put the code in, a box appears but it's blank. Is there something i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are both sites on SSL? If not, using `https` in the URL could trigger CORS errors causing the iframe not to render. Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

well. yes, unless you didn't copy your code correctly to here.
The "https://link" should be the URL of the page you wish to put in that iframe.